# error operand should contain 1 column(s) after comma

Tags: sql

This query is working

```
SELECT 
    *,
    (SELECT dtm 
     FROM vladimir.chatthreadhistory hi 
     WHERE hi.dtm < ch.created 
     ORDER BY hi.dtm DESC 
     LIMIT 1) AS aa 
FROM 
    vladimir.chatmessage ch 
ORDER BY 
    ch.created DESC;
```

but if I want to display more from second select I'm getting this error

```
   SELECT *,(SELECT dtm,threadid from vladimir.chatthreadhistory hi where hi.dtm <ch.created ORDER BY hi.dtm DESC limit 1)as aa 
FROM vladimir.chatmessage ch order by ch.created DESC;
```

Can you tell me why?

Comment: you can't select more than one column in a subquery in projection part of SQL

Comment: @GurwinderSingh Thanks, should I probably use join here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need two different correlated sub-queries. Here is one way

```
SELECT *,
       (SELECT dtm
        FROM   vladimir.chatthreadhistory hi
        WHERE  hi.dtm < ch.created
        ORDER  BY hi.dtm DESC limit 1) AS aa,
       (SELECT threadid
        FROM   vladimir.chatthreadhistory hi
        WHERE  hi.dtm < ch.created
        ORDER  BY hi.dtm DESC limit 1) AS threadid
FROM   vladimir.chatmessage ch
ORDER  BY ch.created DESC;
```

If your `DBMS` supports something similar to `APPLY` operator in `SQL SERVER` then in single query we can select both the columns